# limit property in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

If $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$ in a Hilbert space then $\left<x_n,y_n\right>\rightarrow\left<x,y\right>$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

So the way I started:
using Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
|\left<x_n,y_n\right>-\left<x,y\right>|=|\left<x_n,y_n\right>-\left<x_n,y\right>+\left<x_n,y\right>-\left<x,y\right>|\leq|\left<x_n,y_n-y\right>|+|\left<x_n-x,y\right>|=0
$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.
Is this correct?

Comment: Perfect.  You might want to add that $x_n$ is bounded which is why the left addend on the rightmost expression converges to zero (so as not to make the argument circular that is.)

Comment: I think it's better to have $\langle x,y_n-y\rangle+\langle x_n-x,y_n-y\rangle$ because as is $\langle x_n,y_n-y\rangle$is ambiguous a priori (i.e. $x_n$ could be larger than $y_n-y$).

Comment: @zwim The sequence $x_n$ is bounded.

Comment: @Mark yes, but how do you show that fact if not by saying $\lVert x_n-x\rVert|<\delta$, hence using my proposal ?

Comment: @zwim Usually, the fact that a convergent sequence is bounded is shown separately. This is something which is true for any metric space.

Comment: @Mark You do not need to deal with the boundedness of $x_n$ once you represent $\langle x_n,y_n-y\rangle $ by $\langle x_n-x,y_n-y\rangle+\langle x,y_n-y\rangle $ as proposed by zwim. That way is simpler.